# Möbius inversion across all natural numbers (no divisors)

Tags: summation, inverse-function, arithmetic-functions, mobius-inversion

**EDITED TO ACCOMMODATE COMMENTS:**

I'm trying (self-taught) to understand more about Möbius inversion. Take two arithmetic functions $f$ and $g$ defined by

$$g(n)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)$$

(Presumably $d$ refers to divisors $>0$ and $\le n$). As I understand it, the inverse via Möbius inversion is then

$$f(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)g\biggl(\frac{n}{d}\biggr)$$

My question is this: is it possible to modify this to invert sums that run across *all* natural numbers? In other words, can I invert the following function?

$$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f\bigl(h(x)\bigr)$$

where $h(x)$ is a third arithmetic function that applies $n$ as a variable. An example might be $h(x)=x^n$ - but *please note that this is only an example*, I am after a general solution.

Presumably I need to find a bijective relationship between $d$ and $\mathbb{N}$. If so, how? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Your second function $g(n)$ does not depend on $n$.

Comment: Then I have mis-expressed myself. I'll revisit it.

Comment: If you mean $g(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)$ instead, then $f(n)=g(n)-g(n-1)$. This can be viewed as $f(n)=\sum_{d\le n}\mu^*(d)g(n-d)$ where $\mu^*(0)=1$, $\mu^*(1)=-1$, and $\mu^*(d)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please have a look at my revised version of the question to confirm if your comment is still valid?